# Collision not working for only one object

Tags: collision

I'm trying to make the blanket in the Couch Tutorial (Blender Guru, How to Make a Couch, Part 8), but although every part of my sofa has "Collision" turned on, the side of the sofa is not answering to the collision. The blanket is going through it. Does somebody know what is going on? Thank you, guys! ;-)

[image]

Here are the settings for the side of the sofa, as you see, "Collision" is turned on.

[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: Are there flipped normals?

Comment: Yes seems like flipped normals ... To share file use https://blend-exchange.com given code paste into your Q via edit. BTW you dont need Collision for  blanket and sofa doesnt need Single Sided ON ... try increase Outer Thickness or add some extra loops (geometry) to sofa. Also try apply scale to blanket.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was really the flipped normals. The whole side of the sofa was inverted, I could see it in red with "Face Orientation". And thank you for the suggestion about sending the file, but I didn't manage to send it, once the file is 38 MB and I can send a max 30 MB.